# Get and show partial area of camera view in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I use following codes to take pictures from the camera view.

```
captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {        
        mCamera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {                    
            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {                  
               mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Instead of asking users to shoot a picture, now I need to continuously show a smaller part (e.g., *50% width*) of the camera picture directly to a view (e.g., `ImageView`).

How can I get the current content from the camera and operate to get a part of it? I need a fast way, so as to be in a video streaming manner (better if I could directly realize this by some codes with the `SurfaceHolder` preview configuration).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you correctly. You could use a custom view extending `SurfaceView` to get and show the camera preview ([something like this](https://bitbucket.org/Jagoba/ar-test/src/bb13ef0f65e819d09ebe7dc609f569c0d6d43b82/src/com/jago/camera/CameraPreview.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default), you will probably have to play around with some parameters). Then you could place that view on your layout.